# msal angular getting id_token instead of access_token while calling the api

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Need to call .net core webapi from angular 10 application using msal angular.
Able to get the access token from  this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(scope), validated the access token using jwt.io. But on calling of webapi, the access_token is getting replaced by id_token.
Any idea why is this happening, Am stuck in this issue for past 1 week.

"@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.1",
"msal": "^1.4.2",
.NetCore 3.1
Angular 10

Comment: Hi @learn,  your application is requesting for security token(Id_token) first and then you need to do one more request for access token.

Comment: Had the same problem. In my case, it was the wrong Configuration of the protectedResourceMap.